# Php parse multilevel - xml into array

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to convert xml into php array but somehow i am doing a mistake, can anyone please help me ?

Here the xml formate :

```
<Department Id="3">
    <Week Date="23/03/2020">
        <Class DateTime="23/03/2020 18:00"/>
        <Class DateTime="23/03/2020 18:45"/>
    </Week>
    <Week Date="30/03/2020">
        <Class DateTime="30/03/2020 18:00"/>
        <Class DateTime="30/03/2020 18:45"/>
    </Week>
</Department>
```

Output Need like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [DateTime] => 23/03/2020 18:00
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [DateTime] => 23/03/2020 18:45
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [DateTime] => 30/03/2020 18:00
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [DateTime] => 30/03/2020 18:45
                )
        )   
)
```

This is what i have tried

```
foreach ($xml->children() as $week) {
    foreach ($week->children() as $class) {
        $j = 0;
        foreach ($class->attributes() as $a => $b){
            $results[$i][$j][$a] = (string) $b;
        }
        $j++;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

I dont know whats wrong in my code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a case of getting the right levels in the XML to match the loops, this builds a weeks data at a time and adds it into the overall results...

```
$results = [];
foreach ( $xml->Week as $week ) {
    $weekData = [];
    foreach ( $week->Class as $class )  {
        $weekData[]['DateTime'] = (string)$class['DateTime'];
    }
    $results[] = $weekData;
}
```

To make this load all attributes...

```
$results = [];
foreach ( $xml->Week as $week ) {
    $weekData = [];
    foreach ( $week->Class as $class )  {
        $classData = [];
        foreach ( $class->attributes() as $name => $value )   {
            $classData[$name] = (string)$value;
        }
        $weekData[] = $classData;
    }
    $results[] = $weekData;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just a question if i have more than attributes like DateTime, how will fetch it dynamically ??

Comment: I've added some updated code which adds all attributes of the Class element.